# wso2 1.10 store DefaultApplication Missing

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have installed a standalone instance of wso2 API Manager 1.10.0 with the CARBON-PATCH-4.4.0-0084 installed. I am walking through the PhoneVerification tutorial and have published the API as instructed. I created a new user for the store and am trying to subscribe to the PhoneVerification-2.0.0 API but cannot because there is no DefaultApplication in the Applications dropdown list.  It is missing from the list.  I tried to add and application and get an error dialog saying Missing Parameters.  I am stuck and cannot go any further.  One additional piece of information, I am using mysql instead of the h2 default. I followed all the instructions to setup mysql and had no problems. Also I changed the admin password as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried API Manager 1.10 with security patch CARBON-PATCH-4.4.0-0084 with no issues. I can create APIs and subscribe using the DefaultApplication. I tried with default database and a new user who is assigned to 'Internal/subscriber' role.

Please check if you have any other changes for Store Web app at 'wso2am-1.10.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store'. You have to replace 'store' and 'publisher' apps as instructed in the Readme of patch.

(iii) Merge and Replace resource/store to /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store

(iv) Merge and Replace resource/publisher to /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/publisher

To check if the Mysql configuration worked properly, please check if there are any errors in Carbon log, at 'repository/logs/wso2carbon.log' file related to that. And double check if userstore and api-manager database tables are created properly and configured in 'repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml' properly.

Comment: I have narrowed it down some. I did a complete reinstall and made sure everything was working. I have not as of yet applied the patch. I doing a forward proxy on store and publisher  and have it setup and working but that is where I encounter two problems. The custom icon for the calculator app does not show in the store and the default application does not show up in the dropdown list. Everything else appears to be working. I setup the reverse proxy as outlined here: http://madamadasune.com/2015/08/apache-reverse-proxy-configuration-for-wso2-api-manager/